# Python : Image Clustering

Tags: python, arrays, image, cluster-analysis

can I convert all the images to an array saved in one file csv then use those arrays for clustering,
or do I have to convert one by one image into array form then merge them for used in clustering?

Answer (score 0):

If you want save data for subsequent uses other than this one you should use csv. Otherwise you could load images directly in arrays, in this case take a look at spark.